# GWT - RPC transporting Hibernate object issue

Tags: java, database, hibernate, gwt, rpc

I'm having problem transporting one object via RPC call in GWT. I'm using Spring MVC and Hibernate inside this project.

Here is the **entity class:**

```
@Entity
public class Room implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5924198459524011627L;

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    private Set<Wall> walls = new HashSet<Wall>(0);

    public Room(){
    }

    public Room(String name, String description){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Room(String name, String description, Set<Wall> walls){
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.walls = walls;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROOM_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "ROOM_WALL", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROOM_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "WALL_ID")})
    public Set<Wall> getWalls(){
        return walls;
    }   

    public void setWalls(Set<Wall> walls){
        this.walls = walls;
    }
}
```

Here is my **RoomDAO**:

```
@Repository
public class RoomDAO {

    @Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate hibernate;

    public Room get(Long id){
        return hibernate.get(Room.class, id);
    }

    public void delete(Room entity){
        hibernate.delete(entity);
    }

    public void save(Room entity){
        hibernate.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    }

    private Session getCurrentSession(){
        return hibernate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }   

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Room> list(){
        String queryStr = "from "+Room.class.getSimpleName()+" fetch all properties";
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryStr);
        System.out.println("Room list succesfull");
        return (List<Room>)query.list();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Wall> getWalls(Long id){
        String queryStr = "from "+Wall.class.getSimpleName()+" wl join wl.walls ls where ls.id=:"+id;
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryStr);
        System.out.println("Walls list succesfull");
        return (List<Wall>)query.list();
    }
}
```

Here is the **error message** that I obtain:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = []
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:709)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:748)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(ArrayList_CustomFieldSerializer.java:28)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:474)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:551)
    at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:37)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

I would like to ask if this problem is caused by ManyToMany relation and **Set** used to map the relation between my entities. Because when I transport an object that does not have any relations (ManyToMany or OneToMany etc.) where I use Set, the RPC call works fine.

Could it be the solution to replace Set by List ? I know that List is not effective for database but I don't want to rebuild whole project :D

I found that these problems can be solved by using Dozer for ex.

Thank you very much for your answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem. Have a look at the chapter *Why Hibernate objects can't be understood when they reach the browser world* in the article [Using GWT with Hibernate](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate).

Comment: thanks for your answer :) I've checked the possible solutions... finally I adjusted my Hibernate objects on the Server side and I send them to the client without objects that are not serializable. So I resolve the logic that can't be transported on the server side :)